# how to setup hotmail with laravel 4 mail method?

Tags: php, email, ssl, encryption, laravel

I searched around but people seem to be using gmail setting with laravel instead of hotmail.
I tried with the gmail setting and it works perfectly so I'm trying with hotmail but can't seem to get it to work.
Can someone please give me a hand?
I tried few different settings but none of them works at all.
I tried things like

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.live.com',
'port' => 25,
'encryption' => 'ssl',
```

the above I tried port 587 and port 465 and changed encryption to TLS but none of them works and instead I get errors like

Connection could not be established with host smtp.live.com [ #0]

or error about taking too long to connect to the server that it's not responding.

if I change the 'driver' to 'mail' the page will load without error but nothing in the email is received

I even tried

```
'driver' => 'mail',
'host' => 'pop3.live.com',
'port' => 995,
'encryption' => 'ssl',
```

I still got nothing and if I change the driver to smtp I get errors

Can someone give me a hand with this?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: Use a proper mailing service. Neither Gmail nor Hotmail are intended for this, and they may well shut your access off. Something like Mandrill (http://mandrill.com/, 12k free/month) or Sendgrid (http://sendgrid.com/, 200 free/day) is best.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nevermind I found out. Finally.....

this is how it needs to be setup

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
'port' => 587, ( or 25)
'encryption' => 'tls',
```